# Generate number sequence with step size in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to generate a sequence of numbers using C# linq. Here is how I have done it using for loop.

```
int startingValue = 1;
int endValue = 13;
int increment = 5;
for (int i = startingValue; i <= endValue; i += increment) {
   Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: check this article on [generating sequence numbers in LINQ](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/generating-sequence-numbers-in-linq-query)

Comment: Replace `Console.WriteLine(i)` with `yield return i` and wrap it in a method that returns an `IEnumerable<int>` and you're done. Iterator methods are nice like that.

Comment: Where does this 'need' come from? homework requirements? Otherwise, it's probably better to stick to your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to mimic your procedural code, you can use [TakeWhile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb534804(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
 Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue).
            Select(i => startValue + (i * increment)).
            TakeWhile(i => i <= endValue);
```

But this is to my opinion worse in terms of performance and readability.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to emulate `for` loop:

```
int startingValue = 1;
int endValue = 13;
int increment = 5;

var result = Enumerable
  .Range(0, (endValue - startingValue) / increment + 1)
  .Select(i => startingValue + increment * i);

Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Outcome:

```
1, 6, 11
```

Comment: This is a more efficient than most, if not all, of above solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Not everthing has to be done *in LINQ* to be usasable *like* Linq, you can stick very close to your original:

```
IEnumerable<int> CustomSequence(int startingValue = 1, int endValue = 13, int increment = 5)
{        
    for (int i = startingValue; i <= endValue; i += increment) 
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

Call it like

```
var numbers = CustomSequence();
```

or do any further LINQ on it:

```
var firstTenEvenNumbers = CustomSequence().Where(n => n % 2 == 0).Take(1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems wasteful but the best I can think of is something like this:

```
int startingValue = 1;
int endValue = 13;
int increment = 5;
var sequence = Enumerable.Range(startingValue,(endingValue-startingValue)+1)
               .Where(i=>i%increment == startingValue%increment);
```

Which is hopefully easy to follow. *Logically*, all of the values produced by your `for` loop are congruent to the `startingValue` modulo `increment`. So we just generate *all* of the numbers between `startingValue` and `endingValue` (inclusive) and then filter them based on that observation.

Comment: @mjwills - true, fixed